# Fill missing values in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a current SQL request that works OK

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    firstTab 
LEFT JOIN 
    secondTab ON firstTab.id = secondTab.refId 
LEFT JOIN
    thirdTab ON firstTab.id = thirdTab.refId 
WHERE 
    secondTab.colY IN ('value1', 'value2') 
    AND thirdTab.colZ IN ('value3', 'value4')
```

So far so good.

The problem is that I get the result only for rows when there are data for the values in colA or colB (which is the normal behaviour).

(currently I only get

```
         colY      colZ       currentResult
--------------------------------------------
row1    value1    value3          resultA
row3    value2    value3          resultB
```

)(normal behaviour)

I wish to do fill the missing values with some NULL values in such a way

```
         colY      colZ       currentResult
--------------------------------------------
row1    value1    value3          resultA
row2    value1    value4           NULL
row3    value2    value3          resultB
row4    value2    value4           NULL
```

('value1','value2') and ('value3','value4') are given , I know them in advance

I tried to "init" the result with a cartesian product with CROSS JOIN of secondTab and thirdTab but then I am stuck.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the remark, I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the filtering conditions to the `ON` clauses:

```
Select *
FROM firstTab LEFT JOIN 
     secondTab
     ON firstTab.id = secondTab.refId AND secondTab.colY in ('value1','value2') LEFT JOIN
     thirdTab
     ON firstTab.id = thirdTab.refId and thirdTab.colZ in ('value3','value4');
```

Unmatched values from the `LEFT JOIN` are `NULL`.  The `WHERE` clause will filter these out, turning the outer joins into inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an  FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
Select *
FROM firstTab LEFT JOIN 
     secondTab
     ON firstTab.id = secondTab.refId FULL OUTER JOIN
     thirdTab
     ON firstTab.id = thirdTab.refId 
WHERE secondTab.colY in ('value1','value2') and
      thirdTab.colZ in ('value3','value4')
```

[Join ideas](https://external-preview.redd.it/M5QHWsp2vgZ-3QDZ4m-qS58lsOUgDNHau8trSFzS8H0.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=45aa885fd11dda569ffa363855db14c8a8559fc1)

Comment: thanks MihaiM for your response, I did try the FULL OUTER JOIN but it did not seem to work (or maybe I used it wrong ?)

Comment: With that WHERE clause you'll still get INNER JOIN result.